# Split a series into groups depending on location

Tags: c#, algorithm, split

I have a series of towns with their coordinates (GPS but I can do a projection if needed).

I would like to split them into 4 groups of equal size depending on their location. It doesn't have to be very accurate but I want to have 4 groups which could be "4 regions" including the towns.

I didn't find good articles on this subject, Do you have any idea on how to solve this (in c#) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called "Clustering Problem". You can find a solution in C# close to what you're looking for in [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/12/01/k-means-data-clustering-using-c.aspx)